# httpBody [Any] to alamofire

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire

i need to set body of the request to something like that

```
 let param =  [[["user_id", "=", 31]]]
```

the problem is that body of alamofire is like that [string : Any]
how can i send object [Any]to httpBody

i can't send json because only what accepted by the request is form-data like image show 
[image]

When i add json  raw like that

{"domain" : ["user_id","=",31]}

i'm getting error

```
   {
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"id": null,
"error": {
    "code": 200,
    "message": "Odoo Server Error",
    "data": {
        "name": "werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequest",
        "debug": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/data/som.dev.arkeup.com/server/odoo/http.py\", line 646, in _handle_exception\n    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)\n  File \"/data/som.dev.arkeup.com/server/odoo/http.py\", line 307, in _handle_exception\n    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])\n  File \"/data/som.dev.arkeup.com/server/odoo/tools/pycompat.py\", line 87, in reraise\n    raise value\n  File \"/data/som.dev.arkeup.com/server/odoo/http.py\", line 683, in dispatch\n    result = self._call_function(**self.params)\n  File \"/data/som.dev.arkeup.com/server/odoo/http.py\", line 315, in _call_function\n    raise werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequest(msg % params)\nwerkzeug.exceptions.BadRequest: 400: Bad Request\n",
        "message": "",
        "arguments": [],
        "exception_type": "internal_error"
    }
}
}
```

__________________EDIT

I think if i put this string it's will work [[["user_id", "=", 31]]]

but how can i pass [Any]?  to body ?

_____EDIT

Here my ios code 
        let methodName = HTTPMethod.get
          let headers = [ "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ,"Accept-Encoding" : "application/json", "accept" : "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"]

```
   let data = ["domain":[[["user_id", "=", 31]]]]

    manager.request(urlS!, method: methodName, parameters: data, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers)//.responseJSON{response in
       .responseString(encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) { (response) -> Void in


            switch (response.result)
            {
            case .success:




                }
```

Thank's you for your responses

Comment: Your value doesn't make sense at all. Looks like `user_id` should be the key and the value should be just `31`

Comment: It looks like your data isn't in the quite the same as the postman request. {"domain" : (["user_id","=",31])}

Comment: @SachinVas how can i do the same ?

Comment: let param: (String, String, Int) = ("user_id", "=", 31); let data = ["domain":[param]]; @tamtoum1987

Comment: @Desdenova when i try this raw  : {"user_id" : 31} i have this error  {"error": "search_read() got an unexpected keyword argument '{\"user_id\" : 31}'"}

Comment: Can you clarify that postman image? If you run that do you receive a successful response?

Comment: @Desdenova yes i receive succesful error with form-data and x-www-form-urlencoded  but when i select raw and i try to put json i  m getting error

Comment: @SachinVas i will try your solution

Comment: @SachinVas with your solution i'm getting error like this Printing description of response.result.success:
"{\"error\": \"search_read() got an unexpected keyword argument \'domain[]\'\"}"

Comment: I know with other framework like alamofirexmlRpc i was using body like that [[["user_id", "=", 31]]] and its was working

Comment: Can you post code on how are you reading the data which is sent on the URL?

Comment: how i can i put this on body [[["user_id", "=", 31]]]

Comment: let final: [String:Any] = ["domain":[[["user_id", "=", 31]]]] @tamtoum1987

Comment: @SachinVas but alamofire accept only [String : Any] parameters 
or Data

Comment: @SachinVas i try it it give me error 
Printing description of response.result.success:
"{\"error\": \"search_read() got an unexpected keyword argument \'domain[][][]\'\"}"

Comment: he don't like when i put name domain to him he expect something without dmain like this [[["user_id", "=", 31]]] 

he gonna make me crazy

Comment: Can you post how the server is reading the data?

Comment: on postman i don't know what is exactly form-data if i put data body exactly like form-data it will work

Comment: @SachinVas it's a odoo server 
with a module installed to user Rest i don't have acces :(

Comment: Can you post your iOS code?

Comment: @SachinVas i just put a part of the code

Comment: Can you please post the curl command from the postman?

Comment: @SachinVas its on the image i join to the message for header i add exactly the same as the application and body its on form-data   key domain value [('user_id','=', 31)]

url like this http://som.dev.***.com/api/project.task